# vb.net writing background multithreading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

My application will creates an Excel from DB, creating an excel file takes few minutes of time and till that time the user dont want to wait for the excel to complete, he should start working with the application. Once the excel have been completed the appilcation should po-up message saying, 'Report Sucess'.

can any one tell me how to do this, whtr background thread will help me in this ?

if yes pls provide me some sample, newbie to threading....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you do during the Excel creation.

A very simple and effective way to create and control a background thread is using a     BackgroundWorker.

It very [easy](http://www.vbnettutorial.net/?Id=136&Desc=Vb.Net-BackgroundWorker-To-Invoke-ListBox) to [implement](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/GUI/BackgroundWorkerDemo.htm).

And it's [thread safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You can find a working example I've prepared ([BackgroundWorkerDoStuff](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=669adf1af64df389&sc=documents&id=669ADF1AF64DF389!197#)).

Comment: LeftyX, thanks for your response. Im nnot doing anything great in excel just copying values from DB to excel cells and simple formatting. What i did here is, trd = New Thread(AddressOf ExportToExcel) trd.IsBackground =True 'MainForm.Instance.mnuExit.Enabled = False 'MainForm.Instance.ControlBox = False trd.Start              Now the new thread trd start working as excel everything fine but i want to kill the thread 'trd' after excel operations completed and want to access the main form controls ? when i tried that it throws a error message some 'Circular thread reference error' .

Comment: @user809244: I would suggest you not to use that to access or change your GUI. It's not thread safe. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @LeftyX- That worked but i have issue with the progress bar. The progressbar should be progressed according to the time taken to create the excel. pls tell me where shld i call the method ExportToExcel() in your code.

Comment: @user809244: the even BW_DoWork is where everything happens. your dataset/datareader loop on each row and populate th Excel file. ReportProgress is just a facility to report a progression.I think the best is to calculate a percentage on the number of rows you're elaborating.

Comment: @LeftyX - thanks. i used    MyWorker.ReportProgress(20) and conse: increased the % , and hope it is working fine. Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: @user809244: I am glad I've helped you in some way.

Comment: @LeftyX - i have one more doubt. If ur aware of that pls help.       I want to create a 2 charts of type type of chart (1) line chart (2) Area stacked with the same data from excel sheet using VB.net program. Im able to create one chart (area stacked) but i dont know how to create the other one in the same chart area. This is little urgent, any kind of help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: @user809244: I am afraid I can't help but I can suggest you a good tool I use to generate excel files: http://code.google.com/p/npoi/

Comment: @LeftyX- Thanks. i dont think that will help me :(